# How to solve the "control reaches end of non-void function" warning?

Tags: c, function, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have been getting a compiler error `control reaches end of non-void function`. The code in question [with the if-statement and body of if-statement omitted as `⋯`] is of the form:

```
extern RC_Code_t osa_odm_init (void)
{
    if ( ⋯ )
    {
        ⋯
        ⋯
        return (RC_OK);
    }
}
```

I specified the return value of the function as `void` but I am getting an error. How to fix this?

Comment: The return value type is `RC_Code_t ` , not `void`. The parameter argument list is `void`. If the return type were `void`, then you'd have a whole new problem (`return (RC_OK);` wouldn't make sense).

Comment: [mcve], please!

Comment: Ok,so how to resolve this warning?

Comment: Make sure all paths out the function have a proper `return something;`

Comment: Your `return` statement is only in the `if` block. When that condition fails, you don't execute a proper `return` statement.

Comment: You need to add a `return RC_something;` statement outside the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `control reaches end of non-void function` warning occurs when that function return type is not void, but the function can reach the end *without a `return`*.

It can be caused by control statements such as if-statements and missing return statements.

To answer "*I specified the return value of the function as void but I am getting an error*",

- Your function `osa_odm_init` returns a `RC_Code_t`, not `void`. The `void` is in the arguments, indicating no arguments.

The actual cause is that it returns `RC_Code_t`, but the `return` is only here if the if-statement is true, you are missing the `return` if the if-statement fails. The edited code should be

```
extern RC_Code_t osa_odm_init (void)
{
    if ( odmInitFlag == BOOL_FALSE )
    {
        ........
        ........
        return (RC_OK);
    }
    // This section runs if ( odmIntFlag != BOOL_FALSE )
    // In your original code, you omitted the return
    return RC_ERROR; // Edit: Or return another RC_Code_t result
}
```

Comment: or can i add return 0?

Comment: What is the RC_Code_t type? If it is numeric, than you can do so. To clarify the question, you should state what RC_OK and other RC values mean. I have sent a suggested edit to you that improves the code formatting.

Comment: RC_Code_t is an enum

Comment: Well, for the case if the `if` statement is false, it *still* has to return. Namely, you need to return a different `RC_Code_t` object. Can you please accept my edit suggestion and add how the `RC_Code_t` enum is implemented in your question to clarify it?

Comment: Sorry.it was by mistake..i have reverted it back.